# Does a Dell PowerEdge 1850 have a way to get Molex 4 pin power?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, electrical-power

I have a PCI card that needs 4 pin power hooked up to it and wondering if there is a way to supply it inside this server.

Comment: it appears that this care *may* work without the power connection for self-powered devices, I can't understand why it wouldn't as the 75W you can draw through a PCIe slot should more thatn suffice for the signal pins to work - of course if you wanted to power seven devices off that board then I would understand why the extra 12V would be helpful. That said I found this review (http://www.amazon.com/review/R1CYY8UP9W7C3R) which puts me RIGHT off using that card at all, please have a read so you can bear it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some *awful* things...

I've had to pull power from a SAS backplane drive connector in order to provide a 4-pin Molex connector to a very specialized PCIe card.

What are you trying to do, though?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That. Is. Dirty. But I love it. :)

Comment: I am hoping to add USB 3.0 via this card: [link](http://www.amazon.com/ORICO-PVU3-5O2U-Port-USB-3-0/dp/B0084Z9PMC/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1370876408&sr=1-2&keywords=orico+usb+3.0) , which requires the additional power.

Comment: I could never buy Dell servers - the typeface they use on those riser panels makes my teeth itch...

Comment: How did I guess that this would be @ewwhite ... ?

Comment: @mfinni Am I that predictable?